# Show data on map using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I want to show data on a map using D3. I have the map working with this code :

```
var jMap = $(".map"),
    height = jMap.height(),
    width = jMap.width(),
    mapJsonUrl = 'https://ucarecdn.com/8e1027ea-dafd-4d6c-bf1e-698d305d4760/world110m2.json',
   svg = d3.select(".map").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var getProjection = function(worldJson) {
    // create a first guess for the projection
 var scale = 1,
     offset = [ width / 2, height / 2 ],
     projection = d3.geoEquirectangular().scale( scale ).rotate( [0,0] ).center([0,5]).translate( offset ),
     bounds = mercatorBounds( projection ),
     scaleExtent;

    scale = width / (bounds[ 1 ][ 0 ] - bounds[ 0 ][ 0 ]);
    scaleExtent = [ scale, 10 * scale ];

    projection
      .scale( scaleExtent[ 0 ] );

  return projection;
},

mercatorBounds = function(projection) {
  // find the top left and bottom right of current projection
  var maxlat = 83,
      yaw = projection.rotate()[ 0 ],
      xymax = projection( [ -yaw + 180 - 1e-6, -maxlat ] ),
      xymin = projection( [ -yaw - 180 + 1e-6, maxlat ] );

   return [ xymin, xymax ];
};


d3.json(mapJsonUrl, function (error, worldJson) {
    if (error) throw error;

  var projection = getProjection(),
      path = d3.geoPath().projection( projection );

  svg.selectAll( 'path.land' )
      .data( topojson.feature( worldJson, worldJson.objects.countries ).features )
      .enter().append( 'path' )
      .attr( 'class', 'land' )
      .attr( 'd', path );
});
```

This is my javascript file.

```
<body>

    <div class="map"></div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/2.2.0/topojson.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/index.js"></script>

  </body>
```

And this is my HTML file.

The map is working correct as you can see in the image :
[image: Map with D3 & TopoJson]

So what I want to do now is add data to the map. This is what the data looks like :

```
[{
    "date": "1425168000000",
    "values": [{
        "name": "US",
        "value": 70421276
    }, {
        "name": "DE",
        "value": 5179869
    }, {
        "name": "GB",
        "value": 4515529
    }, {
        "name": "CN",
        "value": 2862945
    }]
```

So I have different json files with this data for each country. For example I want this data on the map with yellow dots, the higer the value the more dots I want to show on the map.

Is this possible with the data and map I have and how do I start with it?

Comment: It is probably possible, but I can imaging the bubble for China (10b+ population) will be extremely large and bubble for Mongolia (3m population), the typical way is to use different shape of colors to represent the data instead of using bubble. I have an example on [github](https://github.com/e-tinkers/freecodecamp/tree/master/data-visualization/choropleth-map), hope it gives you some idea on how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

How about first getting a list of the location of capitals ([here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=16&ved=2ahUKEwjV7cyCpePfAhXGiiwKHdRlCiMQFjAPegQIAxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fesa.un.org%2Funpd%2Fwup%2Fcd-rom%2FWUP2014_XLS_CD_FILES%2FWUP2014-F13-Capital_Cities.xls&usg=AOvVaw336Tofy-azYzn3ouMzUaT1) for instance) and then using the `projection` method to convert lat/lon coordinates to SVG coordinates (as shown in [this](http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/7745589) example):

```
svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(yourData).enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function (d) { return projection(latLon)[0]; })
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return projection(latLon)[1]; })
        .attr("r", function(d) { return d.size; })
        .attr("fill", "yellow");
```

Assuming that you converted the XLS file to a JSON array (by using a CSV file for instance) and having `latLon` property for each capital as an array. And `d.size` contains the values appropriately scaled for the SVG.